# Django complex query comparing 2 models

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

This may be a design question.

Question is "What is the best way to find offers that needs to have feedback sent by logged in user". In Feedbacks site there are 3 tabs: "Sent", "Received", "Send feedback".
"Send feedback" tab there's a table with "Offer id","username(buyer/sender" and "Send feedback" link pointing to feedback form.

Here's the code which should help understand what I mean.

Offers are displayed until some user buys it.
Offer is being closed, and new Order (storing order details) instance is created for this offer.

I'm trying to implement a Feedback app, where both sides of offer transaction can 
send feedback about transaction.

Let's skip the "ended" or "running" offer problem.

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    """Offer is displayed for 5 days, then it's being ended by run everyday cron script.
       If someone buys the offer end_time is being set, and offer is treated as ended.
       Both sides of transaction may send feedback.
    """    
    whose = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="User who has created the offer")
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="")
    field = ()
    fields2 = ()
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, balnk=True, null=True, help_text="Order details")

class Order(models.Model):
    """stores order details like user, date, ip etc."""
    order_1_field_details = ()
    who = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="User who bought the offer")
    offer_id = models.PositiveIntegerField("know it's unnecessary")
    offer_data = models.TextField('offer data dict here')

class Feedback(models.Model):
    offer_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    sent_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Offer sender")
    received_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Offer receiver")

    def get_offer(self):
        try: 
            Offer.objects.get(id=self.offer_id)
        except Offer.DoesNotExist:
            return None  # offer moved to archive
```

In first draft there was a offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer) instead of offer_id field,
but I am going to move some old offers from Offer table to another one for archiving.
I would like the feedback stay even if I 'archive' the offer. In feedback list there will be an 'Offer id" link and for offers older than 60 days user will see "moved to archive" when clicking "details".

All I can think of at the moment is getting offers which hasn't expired, but there was a buyer.

ended() is a manager returning `self.filter(end_date__isnull=False)`

```
offers_with_buyer = models.Q(Offer.objects.ended().filter(whose__exact=request.user, order__isnull=False) | models.Q(Offer.objects.ended().filter(order__who__exact=request.user)
```

How do I check if there's a feedback for these offers ?
I know I should return user and offer id from queryset above and check if they exist in Feedback.offer_id and Feedback.sent_by.. or maybe I should change model design completely ...

Answer (score 1):

First, how you're handling the end date is very contrived. If the offer ends 5 days after it's created, then just set that automatically:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Offer(models.Model):
     ...
     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.end_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=5)

         super(Offer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, just modify your `ended` manager to return instead: `self.filter(end_date__lte=datetime.now())`

However, I generally prefer to add additional methods to my default manager to deal with the data in various ways:

```
class OfferQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def live(self):
        return self.filter(end_date__gt=datetime.now())

    def ended(self):
        return self.filter(end_date__lte=datetime.now())

class OfferManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_query_set(self):
        return OffersQuerySet(self.model)

    def live(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_query_set().live(*args, **kwargs)

    def ended(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_query_set().ended(*args, **kwargs)
```

*(Defining a custom `QuerySet` and then using methods on the `Manager` that just proxy to the `QuerySet` is the way the Django core team does it, and allows you to use the methods anywhere in the chain, instead of just the front.)*

As far as "archiving" your `Offers` go, it's extremely bad practice to divvy out similar data into two different models/tables. It's exponentially increases the order of complexity in your app. If you want to "archive" an offer. Add a field such as:

```
 is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

You can then create another method in your `Manager` and `QuerySet` subclasses to filter out just archived or live offers:

```
 def live(self):
     return self.filter(is_archived=False, end_date__gt=datetime.now())

 def archived(self):
     return self.filter(is_archived=True)
```

If you really need another model (such as for a separate view in the admin for just archived offers) you can create a proxy model:

```
 class ArchivedOfferManager(models.Manager):
     def get_query_set(self):
         return super(ArchivedOfferManager, self).get_query_set().filter(is_archived=True)

     def create(self, **kwargs):
         kwargs['is_archived'] = True
         return super(ArchivedOfferManager, self).create(**kwargs)

 class ArchivedOffer(models.Model)
     class Meta:
         proxy = True

     objects = ArchivedOfferManager()

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.is_archived = True
         super(ArchivedOffer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: There are already 400000+ offers in table. Wouldn't caching the offer table be difficult then ?. I could automaticaly set end_date+5 days ahead when creating new offer (via custom save()) but how would I cache the offer table? Offers are being ended at midnight, so I could use end_date as DateField() and run cache clear at midnight. Using end_date as DateTimeField() -which at the moment is unnecessary - I don't see cache option as every minute/second Offer queryset would change. That's why I chose to end offers manualy by cron script. Maybe is_archived is the way to go. Thanks!